# Process JSONObject to get the items

Tags: java, json, arrays

This code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj= JSONObject.fromString(request.getParameter("parameter"));
System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("dList"));
```

Gave me a string:

```
["ABC","CGR","DRR"]
```

How to process this to get the values? Tried getting as JSONArray like,

```
JSONArray arr= jsonObj.getJSONArray("dList");
```

But showing the following error.

```
JSONObject["dList"] is not a JSONArray.
```

Here is the raw data:

```
 {"sort":null,
 "filterFunction":null,
 "source":["ABC","CGR","DRR"],
 "length":3,
 "source":["ABC","CGR","DRR"],
 "length":3}}
```

I am passing the `dList` as `JSON.encode(dList.source)` from `Flex`.

Comment: Json should be `key : value`, here's only value. how to process it !! Can you show your row data. `Json` data.

Comment: Show your Json data to understand how your input looks like

Comment: Please provide your raw JSON response for us to help you further.

Comment: Did you tried casting it to array? e.g. `JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObj;`

Comment: You can't pass `["ABC","CGR","DRR"]` as value. You have to pass it as `key:value`, otherwise you have to pass it as a string and you will get it as string then you ll ve to manipulate string and get values from it. You have to pass it as:  `["A":"ABC","B":"CGR","C":"DRR"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
To get the jsonobject in the JSON array

     JSONObject object = jsonarray.getJSONObject(index);


To get the values from JSON object

Json values should be Key and value pair format 

    JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(myJsonString);

    String name = myJson.get("name");

**Example**

 String s = "{menu:{\"1\":\"sql\", \"2\":\"android\", \"3\":\"mvc\"}}";
    JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = menu.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = menu.getString(key);
        map.put(key,value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
JSONObject jsonObj= JSONObject.fromString(request.getParameter("parameter"));  // will get  parameter in JSONObject
JSONArray arr= jsonObj.getJSONArray("dList"); // will get dList from jsonObj and stored to JSONArray

for( int i = 0 ; i < arr.length() ; i++ ){ //  will iterate up to length of array
    try { // for to handle JSON Exception
         JSONObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i); // will get ith object into JSONObject from array
         System.out.println(object.toString()); // print object
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Look Running example :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("language", "Java");
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ja.put(jo);

        for( int i = 0 ; i < ja.length() ; i++ ){
             JSONObject object = ja.getJSONObject(i);
             System.out.println(object.getString("language"));
        }   
 }
```

this will print `Java` as output.

**NOT RECOMMENDED but Running if Your data will be of 3 characters fixed :**

**(With String Manipulation)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        String[] myStringArray = {"ABC","CGR","DRR"};
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        j.put("source", myStringArray);
        ja.put(j);
        for( int i = 0 ; i < ja.length() ; i++ ){
            JSONObject object = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            if(object.has("source")){
                String a = object.toString();
                String b = a.substring(a.indexOf("[") + 1, a.lastIndexOf("]"));
                List<String> strArr = Arrays.asList(b.split("\","));
                for(int j1=0; j1<strArr.size();j1++){
                    if(strArr.get(j1).length() == 4){ System.out.println(strArr.get(j1).substring(strArr.get(j1).indexOf("\"")+1));
                    }else if (strArr.get(j1).length() == 5){ System.out.println(strArr.get(j1).substring(strArr.get(j1).indexOf("\"")+1,strArr.get(j1).lastIndexOf("\"") ));
                    }else { System.out.println(strArr.get(j1)); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("parameter"));
JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("dList");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(array.get(i));
}
```

This works if you are using this [Jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)